# Mp2t video internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-video, xbox360, mpeg2-ts

I cannot get xbox-360 Internet Explorer to play a mpeg-2 ts (h264/AAC) file from an html5 video tag within a browser page. Do I need to install a plugin or something to get IE to play it?

I can get an h264 mp4 video to play from a web page in IE with an html 5 video tag. Just not an mpeg 2 ts file. So it is format specific.

Comment: I know I had to install Haali media splitter for Picasa to recognize MTS files, so it's probably not supported out of the box in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link for windows Server 2008,

I am not sure if the link will work in XBOX, but that contains decoder for sure. :)

[`Overview`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2483177)

[`Update Link`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13283)

This is for windows server 2008 only, but I think it should work as File named as windows 6.1 that work well in windows 7 also although there are some exceptions.

if you can find this dll place it in appropriate place manually that will do

`Msmpeg2vdec.dll`

Description for this in the above link also in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd797815%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

IF you have ZUNE! if not please try and download this.. that might solve your issue..
[`Link to zune download for XBOX`](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/music-and-video/zune/software/download)

IF your Box is not updated Please update it here [Link](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/system-updates/system-updates-info)

Let me know if this works..